# Write Consistency in Realm React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

How realm react native achieves write consistency during transaction? Is there any `executeTransaction()` kind of method for `realmJavaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use `realm.Write(() => { ... });` to create a transaction. When the lambda returns, the changes made within the transaction will be persisted atomically.